# VS2008 Save Query Results to file/xml

Tags: sql, visual-studio-2008

When I use the query designers in VS2008, how do I save the results to a file?

The output window is truncating the XML datatype - even if it didn't truncate, it still requires cut and paste to save the results to a file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think the built-in VS2008 query designer is intended or designed for that task. It works well for designing and tweaking queries - but if you need to really extract the data, I would recommend going to the MS SQL Server Management Studio (if you're using SQL Server) or any other dedicated front-end for your database system.